# How can i write in the "Enterprise Trust" Store?

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have a .p7b file with a few certificates and i want to install them in the "Enterprise Trust" Store. A program i want to use expects it there.

I have writte code in c# which extract all the certificates from the file and installs them into a X509Store ("Storename.My") which works.

If i try to use the same code to write in a different store it (which already exists) it creates a new empty store and writes in there.

The StoreName.My is taken from system.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates public enum StoreName, but there is no option for the "Enterprise Trust" store.
So i tried to use the constructor where i can give the StoreName as a string.

I use the certmgr from windows to check what certificats are stored in which stores.

```
// open file
var certificateStore = new CmsSignedData(new 
FileStream(_tempFileName.ToString(), FileMode.Open));

// get all certificats
IX509Store x509Certs = certificateStore.GetCertificates("Collection");
var a = new ArrayList(x509Certs.GetMatches(null));

// this works
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser); 

// this doesnt work
// var store = new X509Store("Enterprise Trust", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

// open store
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

// write in store
foreach (object o in a) {
    var cert = (Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)o;
    var cert509 = new X509Certificate2();
    cert509.Import(cert.GetEncoded());
    store.Add(cert509);
}
store.Close();
```

How do i write correctly in the a store which isnt the StoreName enum?

Comment: 99% sure that the programmatic name of that store is `"Trust"`; but I can't sensibly check that for a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be sure you aren't creating a new store, you can use the OpenFlags value `OpenExistingOnly`.  Asserting that flag and checking for, e.g. `"Trust2"` yields `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.`  Therefore we get the best level of assurance that `"Trust"` is the right answer by specifying it as:

```
using (X509Store store = new X509Store("Trust", StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
    ...
}
```

<sub>(Note that this is less good to use on Linux (.NET Core), because only Windows pre-initializes the stores)</sub>

We can get confirmation on the programmatic name to the display name via the `certutil.exe` command-line utility:

```
>certutil -store trust
trust "Enterprise Trust"
CertUtil: -store command completed successfully.
```

(I just don't have anything in that store)

Comment: The OpenFlag.OpenExistingOnly is really helpful and opening "Trust" works perfectly. thanks alot for you help. i have another question, by trying around alot, i know have a few extra folders including a second "Enterprise Trust" folder and i cant see a way to delete them in the certmgr or in c#. i couldnt find any information to that on the web. do you maybe also know how to do that?

Comment: @ClemensDegasper You'd need to P/Invoke https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certopenstore to set the CERT_STORE_DELETE_FLAG flag.  There's no easy .NET API to do it.